# Horizontally aligned nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices

The first image below looks a bit better than the one on the right, but I had to use phantoms to align the H and I with the line above them. I also forced some vertical space with `\\[0.2em]`.

Both solutions seem hacky. What should I do instead?

[image: Diagram]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, scale=0.9]
\draw[|-|]  (0,0) node[below, align=center] {\\[0.2em]\ch{\phantom{2}H2}} node[left] {$E_0$} --  (0,3) node[left] {$E_1$};
\draw[|-|]  (1,0) node[below, align=center] {\\[0.2em]\ch{\phantom{2}I2}} node[right] {$E_0$} --  (1,1.5) node[right] {$E_1$};

\begin{scope}[xshift=3 cm]

\draw[|-|]  (0,0) node[below, align=center] {\\[0.2em]\ch{H2}} node[left] {$E_0$} --  (0,3) node[left] {$E_1$};
\draw[|-|]  (1,0) node[below, align=center] {\\[0.2em]\ch{I2}} node[right] {$E_0$} --  (1,1.5) node[right] {$E_1$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \ch{H\rlap{2}} works.

Comment: Note that it is probably better to say something like `below={.5\baselineskip+.2em}` rather than using `\\[.2em]` with centring. The `positioning` library may be helpful. All this is off-topic as your question is already answered above.

Comment: @JohnKormylo An answer?

Comment: @cfr - I wasn't sure if this would be regarded as any less hacky.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It is a good answer. Write it down!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, scale=0.9]
\draw[|-|]  (0,0) node[below=.2em] {\ch{H\rlap{2}}} node[left] {$E_0$} --  (0,3) node[left] {$E_1$};
\draw[|-|]  (1,0) node[below=.2em] {\ch{I\rlap{2}}} node[right] {$E_0$} --  (1,1.5) node[right] {$E_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]